# Add different version of framework per schema

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

We have three development environments, so we have an xcode project with three schemas.

The problem is that we have a provider that supply us with three frameworks, one per environment.

We don't know how to automatically attach the right framework per schema/environment, so we have to change it manually.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Do you use any package manager? With Cocoapods it’s fairly easy. You can use per target packages - https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html

Comment: We use SPM and cocoa pods, but for this framework, we have to add manually.

Comment: You mean that this framework is distributed manually, right and the provider does not support cocoapods or other package manager?

Comment: I have a hacky idea for you but you will have to consider the licensing of the package with the provider and within your company that it is ok... You can distribute as a private Cocoapods by yourself. i.e upload the framework to some private repo and have it register in your pod file as a source - something like - source 'git@github.com:company/cocoapods-repo.git'. You can follow the guide here - https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html. In the future it will only require from you to upload the new framework to the repo and update pods

Comment: I thought it. But this requires a pod update on every schema change, isn’t it? Ideally I want a more automatic way.

Comment: You'll need to update the repo and indeed update the pods every time a new version of framework is released. Not aware of a better solution